# logging.pattern.console in application.properties not working

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I'm trying to change the log pattern in my Spring Boot project. I want to modify the `application.properties` file, and according to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) I can do that using the property `logging.pattern.console`. My `application.properties` file looks simply like this:

`logging.pattern.console=%d`

and it should show only the date in the log line, but I keep seeing the default Spring Boot log pattern. Other kind of properties, like `logging.level`, work fine.
What am I missing?
Thanks,
Sara

Comment: It works for me with 1.3.1.RELEASE. What version of Spring Boot are you using? Can you share a sample project that illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue. The problem is with the springboot version only. Here is how i solved it.

**1.** First of all i excluded default logger provided by spring-boot-starter-web In build.gradle file [Note. you can do similar thing for maven as well] . If you are not using spring-boot-starter-web then skip this step.

```
compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.1.RELEASE'){ exclude group: "org.hibernate" exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging' }
```

**2** Now i excluded logback as well, since i used log4j2

```
configurations { provided all*.exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback' }
```

**3**  Now add dependency for log4j2:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'){
     force = true
    }
```

**4** All the above steps we to ensure that log4j2 jar is used correctly. As i said problem arose due to wrong version of springboot. Springboot 1.4x versions like 
1.4.5, 1.4.7 ... doesn't support this feature, you will need to use 1.5x version. 
do the following

Keep this dependency before apply plugin

```
classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.0.RELEASE")
```

and then apply plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
```

Mostly while configuring you have 1,2,3 steps already covered. Just change the version of spring boot to 1.5.0 or above. And apply Plugin org.springframework.boot, It should work like a charm

Answer (score -2):

Just change the pattern to logging.pattern.console = '%d'.

%d is not parsed just surround it with quotes.

Comment: There's no need for the quotes